# How to unit test the side effects of react useEffect() hook using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test my react component below. I am not able to test the side effects of `useEffect()` hook. As you see below, `useEffect()`  has a call to back end API and fetch some data, iterative over the data, and `setUserProducts()` which will be used in its parent component.
But the `useEffect()` is not getting called and not sure how to test its side effects, and because of this, I am not able to test the function `getUserProductList()` inside this component as well.

I tried with the `mount` as well but it is the same. The useEffect() is not getting triggered at all.
I actually want to spy the `fetchUserProductDataFromAPI()` and return some mock data and test the side Effects after re-render.
Any thoughts on how to test the components in this case?

UserProductComponent.js

```
const UserProductComponent = props => {
  const {
    userName,
    setUserProducts    
  } = props

  const getUserProductList = (data) => {
  const userProductList = []
  //logic to iterate over the data and get user product data
    return userProductList
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function pullUserProductDataFromAPI() {
        const { data } = await fetchUserProductDataFromAPI(userName)
        setUserProducts(getUserProductList(data))
    }
    pullUserProductDataFromAPI()
  }, [userName])

  return (
   
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>product name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            userProducts !== undefined &&
            userProducts.map((userProduct) => {
              return (<tr>
                <td>{userProduct}</td>
              </tr>)
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  )
}

export default UserProductComponent
```

===========================
UserProductComponent.test.js

```
describe('UserProductComponent test', () => {
  let props
  let wrapper
  let useEffect

  const mockUseEffect = () => {
    useEffect.mockImplementationOnce(f => f())
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      userName: 'Mark Melon'
      setUserProducts: []
    }

    useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect')
    mockUseEffect()
    mockUseEffect()

    wrapper = shallow(<UserProductComponent {...props} />)
  })

    //test passes successfully
  it('check if it renders compoent UserProductComponents', () => {      
    const header = wrapper.find('table > thead > tr > th')
    expect(UserProductComponent.text()).toBe('product name')
  })

  it('should call setUserProducts()', () => {
     props = {
      userName: 'Mark T'
      setUserProducts: []
    }
    wrapper.setProps({ ...props, ...updatedProps })
    // let useEffect = jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect')
    // const mockUseEffect = () => {
    //   useEffect.mockImplementation(() => console.log('in use effect'))
    // }
    //const wrapper = shallow(<UserProductComponent {...props} {...updatedProps} />)
    expect(updatedProps.setUserProducts).toHaveBeenCalled() //failing has been called 0 times
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi, have you figured it out?